# How to create label with textfield to the right using Material UI React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to figure out how to take either the `TextField` component or use the `Input` and `InputLabel` components to make it so that I have a label and the textfield is to the right of the label?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
       <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}>
                <label htmlFor="name">Name : </label>
                <input type="text" id="name" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                <label htmlFor="age">Age : </label>
                <input type="text" id="age" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                <label htmlFor="hair">Hair : </label>
                <input type="text" id="hair" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                <button>Add New</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

This will give you something like this :

[image]

Comment: Thanks is there a way to do this using react components?

Comment: Yeah, you can wrap this with stateful react component.

Comment: Sorry I meant using a Material UI component such as ```TextField```